# ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number (cx_Oracle)

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

When I am trying to insert data into DB and i can see the above error when i am using below code.

Could you please suggest what else can be done.

Code:

```
list_to_add=['Have you searched','similar question has already been posted']

dsn_tns = cx.makedsn(cred_test['HOST'], cred_test['PORT'], service_name=cred_test['SERVICE_NAME'])

conn = cx.connect(user=cred_test['USER'], password=cred_test['PASWRD'], dsn=dsn_tns)

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.prepare('INSERT INTO Table_name Col_name values (:0)')

cursor.executemany(None,list_to_add)

conn.commit()
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/433

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have minor issues :

1. **ORA-01036** raises due to list elements are not wrapped up with square brackets
2. **ORA-00947** will raise after fixing the first matter, since the `Col_name` is not wrapped up with parentheses within the Insert statement

   ```
   list_to_add=[['Have you searched'],['similar question has already been posted']]

   dsn_tns = cx.makedsn(cred_test['HOST'], cred_test['PORT'], service_name=cred_test['SERVICE_NAME'])

   conn = cx.connect(user=cred_test['USER'], password=cred_test['PASWRD'], dsn=dsn_tns)

   cursor = conn.cursor()

   cursor.prepare('INSERT INTO Table_name(Col_name) VALUES(:0)')

   cursor.executemany(None,list_to_add)

   conn.commit()
   ```